# ReactJS project not working on production server using NGINX

Tags: reactjs, nginx, babeljs

I'm fairly new with getting my react site to run on production, hence this post.

I've a react project working like charm on local, but on nginx server it doesn't work. The title does appear but the whole page is blank. Console error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. I've setup babel & webpack config as well as created a build too, but doesn't seem to solve the issue.

I also cloned react starter projects from github and configured babel but still doesn't work and i can't see any specific error that can help me to get this running.

my package.json at the moment

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "--- first, you should install node and npm.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: You said the app is running locally just fine... But is your build successfully running locally? Is your build working on serverless hosts like Netlify, Vercel, or Firebase? If you are new with deploying react apps I would start with a serverless host like the ones I mentioned, and then go up to nginx

Comment: thanks @gemanepa! Helpful suggestion. I finally deployed it on heroku & its working smoothly! much thanks

Comment: can you suggest why it didn't work on my nginx server? keen to figure out a solution